# Why can't I find Adobe Extract in my cloud Assets anymore?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, css, creative-cloud

In the past I've been able to open the "My Assets" page and upon viewing a PSD I could've extract CSS information from the Extract tab, like it's still being explained here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/extract-css-images-psd-files.html

I didn't use it for a couple of months and now when I'm back the tab is gone. I have a free account but this service *was* free (it's even stated in the above link).

Any ideas? Did Adobe put it behind a pay-wall without telling anyone? (Couldn't find any post about it).

Comment: You have a free account for what? isn't Photoshop CC always a paid subscription? Have you tried contacting Adobe about it?

Comment: @Luciano Just an Adobe account. I don't have any Adobe program installed (this is why I need the Adobe Extract so badly to extract information from PSD files). Didn't contact their support yet, looked for it but they made it very cumbersome to contact them. Their help page is clearly stating the feature should be available.

Comment: It says there: "The Assets panel is not available when you click a link from another user to view a PSD file." Also "If you shared a PSD file prior to the release of Extract in late August 2014, the PSD file will not have the Extract tab activated." Is either your case?

Comment: @Luciano Thanks. It's a PSD I've uploaded a few days ago by myself and didn't share with anyone, so I guess neither is my case. Can you confirm that Extract is working for paid users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They brought the tool back online on the 3rd of August, after receiving negative feedback from customers - see https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2158417.

Answer (score 1):

I just got off the phone with support. The Extract option is no longer available as of last month. Real shame!

Comment: Thanks, same here, I'm a FED too and need Photoshop only to extract styles and not to author them.